# Unable to fetch names ending with a character in oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, wildcard, sql-like

[Oracle - Run SQL Command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwiSj.png)

I have given the proper syntax but I couldn't fetch the information...Please help!!!

Here is my query...

```
SQL> select fname from faculty where fname like 'A%';
FNAME
------------------------------
Amit
Aman
```

```
SQL> select fname from faculty where fname like '%';

FNAME
------------------------------
Amit
Aman
Sumit
Suman
Sumathi
```

```
SQL> select fname from faculty where fname like '%n';

no rows selected
```

Comment: Please, show the output of `describe faculty`

Comment: A very helpful function that you can use for diagnosing such problems is `dump`. What is the result of `select fname, dump(fname) as dump_fname from faculty`? Perhaps add `dump(fname, 17) as dump17_fname` to the `select` list also. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions046.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be related to the datatype of column FNAME. Is it `CHAR`? If So, Oracle will append extra spaces after the string and then your string would not match with your specified selection criteria.

To make it more clear, You can try below query -

```
SELECT fname FROM faculty WHERE TRIM(fname) LIKE '%n';
```

This will trim extra spaces and then might fetch the expected result.

For further assistance, Please post the structure of your table.